# Single view page permalink empty with Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I've set up two routes in Iron-Router: 'home' (a paged list of all post) and 'doc' (a detail view). The home page loads just fine, but the detail view can only be loaded if the home page has been viewed previously. Otherwise it will render empty – and it can't be used as a permalink.

This will always load:
http://localhost:3000/

This will only load if 'home' has been viewed before:
http://localhost:3000/doc/tZFawq8cgf43hZBaJ

**the routes:**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/'
    });
    this.route('doc', {
        path: '/doc/:_id',
        data: function() {
            return MyPix.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
        }
    });
});
```

**the doc template:**

```
<template name="doc">
    <h1>{{this.name}}</h1>
    <img src="{{ this.url store='OriginalRetinaPix' }}" width="{{ this.metadata.width }}" height="{{ this.metadata.height }}" />
</template>
```

**publish/subscribe:**

```
Meteor.publish('MyPix', function(cursor) {
    Counts.publish(this, 'numberOfPosts', MyPix.find(), { noReady: true });
    return MyPix.find({}, {sort: {uploadedAt: -1}, limit: 4, skip: cursor});
});

if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Session.setDefault('docCursor', 0);
    console.log('docCursor: ' + Session.get('docCursor'));
    Meteor.autorun(function(){
        Meteor.subscribe('MyPix', Session.get('docCursor'));
    })
}
```

btw: the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/c6y/eboydb/commit/e31fa4f5520f318e54cc0686d23f1f974534a78d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your "doc" route, you should use the `waitOn` in order to have the data ready on page load. Add a loading template in the `Router.configure` as well

I recommend you to upgrade to the new `iron:router` routes declarations and also add `meteorhacks:subs-manager` for better cache on the subscriptions.

This is an example that should work in your case

```
var subs = new SubsManager();
Router.route('/doc/:_id', {
  name: 'doc',
  template: 'doc',
  waitOn: function() {
    return subs.subscribe('aPix', this.params._id);
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      apix: MyPix.findOne({
        _id: this.params._id
      })
    };
  }
});
```

and on the server side create a `publications.js`

```
Meteor.publish('aPix', function(id) {
  check(id, String);
  return MyPix.find(id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @radu-chiriac! – this works for me – with a small edit. The data had to be changed to `data: function() { return MyPix.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); } ` One thing I don't understand in the publish function is why it works with `MyPix.find(id)` – instead of `MyPix.find(_id)`

Comment: Found the answer to my last question in the above comment (about the id name): it's just the argument's name. I'm a bit embarrassed ... ;) Thanks again!

Comment: true, if you don't want to have it as a template variable for the moment. When you'll have more subscriptions per route, make sure you return them as an Object as I did with "apix". As for the `publications.js` the "id" is passed as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/'
    });
    this.route('doc', {
        path: '/doc/:_id',
        waitOn: function(){ 
             return Meteor.subscribe('MyPix');
        },
        data: function() {
            return MyPix.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
        }
    });
});
```

Also you subscription should look like this.

```
Meteor.publish('MyPix', function(cursor) {
    //Counts.publish(this, 'numberOfPosts', MyPix.find(), { noReady: true });
    return MyPix.find({});
});
```

Also Add, `meteor add sacha:spin`, because when you have a lot of people, the subscription will be have a little delay.

Add this to each route.

```
loadingTemplate: "loading"

<template name="loading">
    {{> spinner}}
</template>

Router.onBeforeAction("loading");
```

Just in case you are showing 100+ images on `'home'` and someone enter and have a slow connection, he will think that the page load empty, or something.

Comment: Thanks @Ethaan! The waitOn function solved the basic problem! But I went with the approach of creating a separate subscription for the ids only (as suggested above). This keeps my current paging on 'home' intact – and the published dataset is smaller (if I understand correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You only subscribe to a subset of all the documents. If you directly go to `/doc/tZFawq8cgf43hZBaJ`, the document with the id `tZFawq8cgf43hZBaJ` may not be part of the subset of documents you receive on the client.

Note: if this answer is correct, you should be able to directly go to `/doc/<id>` for those documents showing up first on the home page (on the first page, when the session variable `docCursor` is `0`).

Comment: yes that what I was thinking as well. But I had the problem even if I took one of the four _id on the first page. The waitOn function seems to be the solution as suggested in the answers below. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Kai, I thought `waitOn` could be the problem too, but it doesn't make sense. The `data` function in your route is reactive, so it's recomputed when the client receives new info from the server that effects the cursor in it, which should lead to that the document is correctly rendered after a while (when the subscription is ready). Strange.